# Array.map() doesn't render React component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am having a problem where i'm trying to render pass an array's data to a card component but it doesn't appear on the page, the card component renders normally on its own:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Grid, Card, Segment, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import ArticleCard from './ArticleCard';


export default class NewsGrid extends Component {
    render() {
        const {News} = this.props
        console.log(News)

        return (
            <div>
                <Container style={{marginTop: '7%'}}>
                <Grid stackable divided >
                    <Grid.Column style={{width: '66.66%'}}>
                        <Card.Group>
                            {
                                News.map(({id, ...otherArticleProps}) => (
                                    <ArticleCard key={id} {...otherArticleProps} />
                                ))
                            }
                        </Card.Group>
                    </Grid.Column>

                </Grid>
            </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

console.log() shows that the data is actually there

[image]

and i'm passing the array as props from the parent page component, the data is delivered through the flamelink API in useEffect as shown bellow:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import NewsGrid from '../components/NewsGrid';
import BusinessContainer from '../components/BusinessContainer';
import PolitiqueContainer from './../components/PolitiqueContainer';
import app from '../Firebase';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const Homepage = () => {
    const [News] = useState([])
    const [Business] = useState([])
    const [Politique] = useState([])
    const [Opinion] = useState([])
    const [Blog] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        app.content.get({schemaKey: 'articles',
                        fields: ['title', 'author', 'date', 'thumbnail', 'slug', 'summary', 'category', 'id'],
                        orderBy:{field: 'date',
                        order: 'desc'},
                         })
        .then(articles => {
            for(var propName in articles) {
                const propValue = articles[propName]

                switch(propValue.category) {
                    default :
                        break;
                    case 'News': 
                        News.push(propValue)
                        break;
                    case 'Business': 
                        Business.push(propValue)
                        break;
                    case 'Politique': 
                        Politique.push(propValue)
                        break;
                    case 'Opinion': 
                        Opinion.push(propValue)
                        break;
                    case 'Blog': 
                        Blog.push(propValue)
                        break;

                }
            }
        })
    })


    return (
        <div >
            <NewsGrid  News={News} Opinion={Opinion} Blog={Blog} />
            <BusinessContainer  content={Business} />
            <PolitiqueContainer  content={Politique} />

        </div>
    );
};

export default withRouter(Homepage);
```

I am using firebase as a backend combined with Flamelink for the CMS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should not [mutate state](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/) in React, `useState` provides a second argument that you can use to change state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `const [News] = React.useState([])`, any changes you make to `News` will not be reflected in your React application, since mutating `News` will not update the state of your component. If you want to update the state of `News`, you need to use the state dispatch function provided by `React.useState`. Try this instead:

```js
const [News, updateNews] = React.useState([])

// We can't use News.push('Some news'), but we can update News this way:
updateNews([...News, 'Some news'])
```

Comment: While this explanation is not technically accurate, this would solve the problem, and is the correct way to use react hooks. `News` **is** mutable, as neither the `const` keyword nor react enforce immutability, but the state will not update and re-render the component without calling the hook method to update that piece of state, or `setState`

Answer (score 1):

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import NewsGrid from '../components/NewsGrid';
    import BusinessContainer from '../components/BusinessContainer';
    import PolitiqueContainer from './../components/PolitiqueContainer';
    import app from '../Firebase';
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

    const Homepage = () => {
      const [news, setNews] = useState([]);
      const [business, setBusiness] = useState([]);
      const [politique, setPolitique] = useState([]);

  const [opinion, setOpinion] = useState([]);
  const [blog, setBlog] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    app.content
      .get({
        schemaKey: 'articles',
        fields: ['title', 'author', 'date', 'thumbnail', 'slug', 'summary', 'category', 'id'],
        orderBy: { field: 'date', order: 'desc' },
      })
      .then(articles => {
        for (let propName in articles) {
          const propValue = articles[propName];

          switch (propValue.category) {
            case 'News':
              setNews(propValue);
              break;
            case 'Business':
              setBusiness(propValue);
              break;
            case 'Politique':
              setPolitique(propValue);
              break;
            case 'Opinion':
              setOpinion(propValue);
              break;
            case 'Blog':
              setBlog(propValue);
              break;
            default:
                break;
          }
        }
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <NewsGrid News={news} Opinion={opinion} Blog={blog} />
      <BusinessContainer content={business} />
      <PolitiqueContainer content={politique} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Homepage);
```

I would suggest using camel case variables:

```
const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState();
```

(https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and to add the `[]` to the `useEffect` array of dependencies. This will ensure that the `useEffect` will trigger only a single time. Hope that this helps.